# Is my vegan icing shelf stable?

Tags: baking, storage-lifetime, icing

I make a vegan buttercream icing with Crisco, powdered sugar, vanilla extract, and soy milk/nut milk/water. If I skip the soy milk/nut milk and use water for the liquid, is the icing totally shelf stable, considering that all of the individual ingredients are shelf stable for months-years?

[EDIT]
Ok, it is not shelf stable. How can I find out how long it can be left out at room temperature? I have seen people online saying anywhere from 2 days to 2 weeks.

Comment: Do you have a basement you could store it in?  Using water would definitely help.  How about getting some ice cubes and a cooler?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @aparente001! I could technically fit it in the fridge if needed. I'm just trying to figure out how long it can be left out at room temp.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not shelf stable, with neither water nor milk.

> considering that all of the individual ingredients are shelf stable

Food safety doesn't work that way. It is not each ingredient separately that goes bad, it is the whole product, regradless of what went into it. And the mixture you describe has no good reason to be shelf stable. See also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.

Comment: A few sites I've seen seem to say it would be OK out of the fridge for 2 weeks or so, but I'm still looking for a better/more reliable source for that. That's what I would have assumed if I had to guess, as well.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph is right, but many icings *are* shelf stable so it's not as clear-cut as you imply.  That's because they're mostly sugar, very little water and that not available for bad things to grow.  Buttercream (non-vegan) isn't one of the more stable ones, but still keeps better than the ingredients at room temp according to many sources, which quote 2-3 days.  Royal and fondant icings are routinely kept for weeks (Christmas cakes) to years (wedding cakes) for comparison

Comment: How do I find an official answer for how long it can stay at room temp for?

Comment: @kayk as per the FAQ linked in my last comment: "See rule number 2 above: The general guideline for perishable foods is that you want them to be in the danger zone (40-140°F, 4-60°C) for no more than 2 hours (1 hour on a hot day).".

Comment: @ChrisH I would consider foods like dried royal icing to "have a good reason to be shelf stable" as per the second paragraph :) Indeed, there are some cases where the mixture happens to have the same shelf life as the components, but my point was that this is the exception, not the rule, and that the icing described above wouldn't fall under that exception.

Comment: Real buttercream is widely listed as being OK in the danger zone for days (maybe there's an official standard for an official recipe, or more likely something properly tested) so it's a more interesting problem than it initially seems.